# Baysian Network Calculation of P(L1|i0) from Kollar Student Network

Tags: probability, bayesian-networks

In Daphne Koller's Student Network Model:
[The pdf in the link below: Reasoning Patterns, gives the graphical representation of the Student Baysian Network](http://spark-university.s3.amazonaws.com/stanford-pgm/slides/2.1.2-Repn-BNs-patterns.pdf)

The problem I'm having is to calculate P(L1 | i0), that is the probability the student gets a high letter of recommendation L1 given he's not that smart i0. Since L1 has no conditional distribution with intelligence i, but both i and L have conditional distributions with G. The Joint Distribution is:

```
P(L1 i0 G) = P(L1 | G)P(G | i0)P(i0)
```

Since L depends on i0 through G: 
    P(L1 | G)P(G | i0) = P(L1|i0)
Also, L and i0 have no conditional distribution so:
    P(L1 i0 G) -> P(L1 G)P(i0 G) = 0.5x0.5 = 0.25
This gives:
    P(L1|i0) = P(L1 i0 G)/P(i0)
From the model:
    P(i0) = 0.7
This gives P(L1 | i0) = 0.25/0.7 = 0.357
The answer in the Link above is 0.39

How do you get that answer?

Answer (score 0):

This calculation of P(i1|g3) yields the answer given by Koller in her lecture given above. This calculation is identical to that which yields the correct answer to the question above. I give this one since it is slightly more compact than the probability P(L1|i0) since it involves 2 not 3 levels of the diagram. Please refer to the PGM (diagram) given in the pdf link in the original question above.

```
P(i1 g3) = Σ_d P(i1 g3 d) and P(i1|g3) = P(i1 g3)/P(g3)
```

Joint Distribution (from the diagram) => P(i1 d g3) = P(i1)P(d)P(g3|i,d)

```
P(i1 g3) = Σ_d P(i1 g3 d) = P(i1)Σ_d P(d)P(g3|i1 d)

Σ_d P(d)P(g3|i1 d) = P(d0)P(g3|i1 d0) + P(d1)P(g3|i1 d1)
                              = 0.6*0.02 + 0.4*0.2 = 0.012 + 0.08 = 0.092
P(i1 g3) = P(i1)*0.0812 = 0.3*0.092

P(g3) = Σ_i,d P(i d g3) = P(g3|i=0,d=0)P(i=0)P(d=0)
                                  + P(g3|i=0,d=1)P(i=0)P(d=1)
                                  + P(g3|i=1,d=0)P(i=1)P(d=0)
                                  + P(g3|i=1,d=1)P(i=1)P(d=1)
= 0.3*0.7*0.6 + 0.7*0.7*0.4 + 0.02*0.3*0.6 + 0.2*0.3*0.4 
= 0.126 + 0.196 + 0.0036 + 0.024 = 0.3496

P(i1|g3) = P(i1 g3)/P(g3) = 0.3*0.092/0.3496 = 0.0789
```

Koller answer ~ 0.08